# Strictly convex function and second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $f(x)=x^2+e^x$ since $f''(x)=2+e^x>0$ always, can I say that the function is strictly convex?

Comment: $x \mapsto x^4$ is strictly convex but $f''(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the second derivative is positive, then it is [strictly convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

This is a sufficient condition but not a necessary condition.

Furthermore, since the second derivative is at least $2>0$, it is strongly convex.